# Unwanted gray background in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background

I have been editing the code of my Tumblr theme and realized that something causes one of the tags to have a gray color background, but i cant find which part of the code is causing this. I used Inspect Element feature and it doesnt reveal the problematic code!

It is perhaps worth mentioning that this happens only when I'm visiting the page in Google Chrome! IE and Firefox show no gray background.

Here is the link to the page http://xziii.tumblr.com/

What do you think is the problem and how can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please show us any screenshots, because I can't notice any grey background element in the link you provided. Maybe it's being caused by an extension.

Comment: extensions! yes. i found the extension that was causing the problem and deactivated it and the gray background is gone. thank you and @Sebastian for your answers.

Comment: @xziii Which extension caused it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reconstruct your problem, there are no grey bars. Are you using any browser-addons or extensions that could cause this problem?